# Matching data inside a double quote using preg_match_all

Tags: php, json, preg-match-all, data-extraction

The data given below is in a format like "name":"Value", "name2":"Value 2", "name3":"Value 3"

```
$datadump = '"Waived":"Waived", "Until":" until", "HeaderBanInfo":"Ban Info", "StatusLabel":"Current Status:", "StatusBanned":"BANNED", "StatusWarned":"WARNED", "StatusSuspended":"SUSPENDED", "StatusActive":"ACTIVE"';
```

I was trying to extract the **names** using php

```
    $pattern = '/"(.*?)":/si';
preg_match_all($pattern, $datadump, $output);
```

But it's not working.
Hope, somebody who knows to fix it will help me.
Thank You.

Comment: `$pattern = '/\"([^\"]+)\"\:/';`

Answer (score 0):

This would work fine:

```
$datadump = '"Waived":"Waived", "Until":" until", "HeaderBanInfo":"Ban Info",      "StatusLabel":"Current Status:", "StatusBanned":"BANNED", "StatusWarned":"WARNED", "StatusSuspended":"SUSPENDED", "StatusActive":"ACTIVE"';
$pattern = '/\"([a-zA-Z\s]*?)\":/si';
preg_match_all($pattern, $datadump, $output);
$names = $output[1];
echo $names[2]; /* this is a simple test */
```

**EDIT (for alphanumeric names only)**

```
$datadump = '"a0":"Waived", "Until":" until", "HeaderBanInfo":"Ban Info",      "StatusLabel":"Current Status:", "StatusBanned":"BANNED", "StatusWarned":"WARNED", "StatusSuspended":"SUSPENDED", "StatusActive":"ACTIVE"';
$pattern = '/\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)\":/si';
preg_match_all($pattern, $datadump, $output);
$names = $output[1];
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($names); $i++)
   echo $names[$i] . "\n";
```

**EDIT2 (it allows spaces between a name and a colon)**

```
$datadump = '"a0" : "Waived", "Until":" until", "HeaderBanInfo":"Ban Info",      "StatusLabel":"Current Status:", "StatusBanned":"BANNED", "StatusWarned":"WARNED", "StatusSuspended":"SUSPENDED", "StatusActive":"ACTIVE"';
$pattern = '/\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)\"[\s]*:/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $datadump, $output);
$names = $output[1];
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($names); $i++)
   echo $names[$i] . "\n";
```

Comment: I'm also wondering. When I directly run the code its working but when $datadump is changed it fails.

$datadump = file_get_contents($datafile);

Comment: Well, you must say what do you mean for "name". In my example a name can contain only lowercase or uppercase letters or spaces. If your name contains for example a digit, it doesn't work fine!

Comment: "name" will be an alphanumeric string without space

Comment: The format of the variable $datadump is the same that you've written above?

Comment: I've updated the solution under "EDIT2", please give me a more detailed feedback about the error!

Comment: Edit2 didn't work as well. But, suppose I am giving the pattern
$pat1 = '/, (.*?):/si';
it works, even though the first value will not be recorded. But when I apply double quote, it fails. like this
$pat1 = '/, "(.*?)":/si';

Comment: try this $pattern = '/\"(.*?)\":\".*?\"/si';

Answer (score 0):

may be this helps you (i am not sure in which format you want the output)

```
$datadump = '"Waived":"Waived", "Until":" until", "HeaderBanInfo":"Ban Info",      "StatusLabel":"Current Status:", "StatusBanned":"BANNED", "StatusWarned":"WARNED", "StatusSuspended":"SUSPENDED", "StatusActive":"ACTIVE"';

print_r(explode(':',str_replace(',',':',$datadump)))
```

***output:***

```
[0] => "Waived"
[1] => "Waived"
[2] =>  "Until"
[3] => " until"
[4] =>  "HeaderBanInfo"
[5] => "Ban Info"
[6] =>       "StatusLabel"
[7] => "Current Status
[8] => "
[9] =>  "StatusBanned"
[10] => "BANNED"
[11] =>  "StatusWarned"
[12] => "WARNED"
[13] =>  "StatusSuspended"
[14] => "SUSPENDED"
[15] =>  "StatusActive"
[16] => "ACTIVE"
```

Comment: I need only the names

Answer (score 0):

try this
$pattern = '/\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)\":/si';

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as it's not clear from your question which name you want. Below code shows how to get any of the names:

**For getting the first names:**

```
$datadump = '"Waived":"Waived", "Until":" until", "HeaderBanInfo":"Ban Info", "StatusLabel":"Current Status:", "StatusBanned":"BANNED", "StatusWarned":"WARNED", "StatusSuspended":"SUSPENDED", "StatusActive":"ACTIVE"';

$pattern_for_1st_name = '/"([a-zA-Z:\s]*?)":/';

preg_match_all($pattern_for_1st_name, $datadump, $output);

var_dump($output[1]);
```

This will output the first names in the pair:

```
array(8) { [0]=> string(6) "Waived" [1]=> string(5) "Until" [2]=> string(13) "HeaderBanInfo" [3]=> string(11) "StatusLabel" [4]=> string(12) "StatusBanned" [5]=> string(12) "StatusWarned" [6]=> string(15) "StatusSuspended" [7]=> string(12) "StatusActive" }
```

**For getting the second names:**

Now if you want the second names in the pair, below is the pattern for it:

```
 $pattern_for_2nd_name = '/:"([a-zA-Z:\s]*?)"/';

 preg_match_all($pattern_for_2nd_name, $datadump, $output);

 var_dump($output[1]);
```

This will output the second names:

```
array(8) { [0]=> string(6) "Waived" [1]=> string(6) " until" [2]=> string(8) "Ban Info" [3]=> string(15) "Current Status:" [4]=> string(6) "BANNED" [5]=> string(6) "WARNED" [6]=> string(9) "SUSPENDED" [7]=> string(6) "ACTIVE" }
```

I don't know if your data has actually the `Current Status:` word or the colon was a typo, so included the colon for the match also.

Answer (score 0):

Since your input string is JSON, you don't need to use preg_match_all, it's better to use your data format:

```
print_r(array_keys(json_decode('{' . $datadump . '}', true)));
```

**PHP Manual:**
[json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
[array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

**About your pattern:**
It doesn't work because `.*?` allows any kind of characters including `"`. The regex engine will proceed the string from left to right, character by character, and will give a match as soon as possible. This is the reason why your second result is: `"Waived", "Until":`

To avoid these results, a way is to forbid the `"` using a negated character class in place of the dot:
`/"([^"]+)":/` *(note that using this, the lazy quantifier is no more needed.)*

Answer (score 0):

Check my [solution](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28ec9cf70b6b973a367b854234ef096d5749f1b1):

```
json_decode('{'.$datadump.'}');
```

LOL